# oAuth disabled on google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Since yesterday, a google script getting all my YouTube stats worked properly.

Today I'm receiving this error:

```
    401. That’s an error.

    Error: disabled_client

    The OAuth client was disabled.

    Request Details
    client_id=187588340283-749l4sdq2r178904t3hi6nhb76fu7jtd.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri=https://script.google.com/oauthcallback
state=ACjPJvHWEix1jjrF0QVcY2oh9beQ8PzX2w6-hNX6C2wlG5IOJ9qt6PVe09UBoqOVl0vK-Zr0xeRb4X2O7tLbj6NMa-21YfUVmhdG_dLmVRhsT_0vL0iclongzUGvfo7IS2VGmecyct3ZVNawFq4P_k0sgV-woTGyE6Pgm8CmuY9OzoMTL9rV09D3XMSGnmXYGspdKbQYXVC1SpTgzOrz2bHNDcN13wrp1Z7RRLBRY5za7xa0czgTYzFHvdyMa4CsOEUpzBHts9Tst8hH5FAL8SQ5a2sTmNUUd0T-iGV1JpKYfHYlGPaHqq8bK9nzrHQocW4RJPvVi1XCeX2H4paK8bgRn0BhpcA
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
    response_type=none gsession
    access_type=offline
    approval_prompt=force
   hl=en
```

can't figured out how to fix or running the script, and I've googled all the possible solutions :(

Comment: What is your script code?

Comment: it's a collection of JS. More or less similar to this: https://dev.to/rick_viscomi/using-sheets-and-the-youtube-api-to-track-video-analytics-6el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted: The solution: - open the script - click Resources > Cloud Platform project - click on the bound project